# Include pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 in Cmake

Tags: c, cmake, glib

I am building c code using cmake on debian11. As I am not much know cmake.
When i build the code i got errot

```
 fatal error: gio/gio.h: No such file or directory
   17 | #include <gio/gio.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I installed glib library and check as well which present in my system

```
oot@rpi4-20210823:~/iot-hub-device-update# ls /usr/include/g
gconv.h             gdk-pixbuf-2.0/     gio-unix-2.0/       glob.h              gnumake.h           grp.h               gsl/                gtk-2.0/
gdb/                getopt.h            glib-2.0/           gnu-versions.h      graphite2/          gshadow.h           gtest/              gtk-unix-print-2.0/
root@rpi4-20210823:~/iot-hub-device-update# ls /usr/include/glib-2.0/
```

So afrer searching internet found that need to build with below argument `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` .
Output is

````
This is output for ```root@rpi4-20210823:~/iot-hub-device-update# pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0
-pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lharfbuzz -lfontconfig -lfreetype```
````

But i did not find the way to include this one in cmake.

Aslo tried other option by adding below portion in cmaketest file

```
pkg_check_modules(GTK "gtk+-2.0")
include_directories(${target_name} PUBLIC  ${GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${target_name} PUBLIC ${GTK_LIBRARIES})
target_compile_options(${target_name} PUBLIC ${GTK_CFLAGS_OTHER})
```

But no used please help to solve problem

Thanks

Comment: If you run `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` in a terminal, what does it output? And what is the output of `ls /usr/include/glib-2.0/` (since you forgot to paste it)?

Comment: Since you pass a target name, you probably want `target_include_directories` isntead of `include_directories`.

Comment: Also, in your `CMakeLists.txt` file, try `message("GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS = '${GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS}'")` to see that it's set correctly (and matches the output of the `pkg-config` command).

Comment: By the way, please **[edit]** your question to include relevant information.

Comment: I have edit question and print the output of pkg-config

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude message output and pkg output seem to similar and also replace the target_include_directories  but still getting same error

Comment: And if you do `ls /usr/include/glib-2.0/` there's a `gio` directory listed? And inside of it there's a `gio.h` file? What is the output if you do e.g. `find /usr/include -name gio.h`? Is the header file found where expected? Or at all?

Answer (score 0):

**Always use imported targets** when they're available. CMake's PkgConfig supports creating imported targets. Hence, you should use them. Here's a simple example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(example)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET "gtk+-2.0")

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE PkgConfig::GTK)
```

Here's my `main.cpp` for testing:

```
#include <gio/gio.h>

int main () { return 0; }
```

Here's what I see at the terminal:

```
alex@Alex-Desktop:~/test$ cmake -G Ninja -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1")
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-2.0'
--   Found gtk+-2.0, version 2.24.32
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/alex/test/build
alex@Alex-Desktop:~/test$ cmake --build build --verbose
[1/2] /usr/bin/c++  -isystem /usr/include/gtk-2.0 -isystem /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -isystem /usr/include/pango-1.0 -isystem /usr/include/atk-1.0 -isystem /usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -isystem /usr/include/libmount -isystem /usr/include/blkid -isystem /usr/include/fribidi -isystem /usr/include/cairo -isystem /usr/include/pixman-1 -isystem /usr/include/harfbuzz -isystem /usr/include/glib-2.0 -isystem /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -isystem /usr/include/uuid -isystem /usr/include/freetype2 -isystem /usr/include/libpng16 -O3 -DNDEBUG -pthread -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/alex/test/main.cpp
[2/2] : && /usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG  CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -o main  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so && :
```

Comment: Yes i have solved the problem the same way where i need to include the package separately.i used``` find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET "gtk+-2.0")```